# How keyword type gets stored and analyzed in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

As per my understanding, Keyword type will not be analyzed and be stored as an exact term. For example "shut down" will get stored as "shut down" in elastic search whereas text type will analyze using default or custom analyzer(if specified) and it'll separate "shut down" as [shut , down] into two words and store it in ES. This applies for searching also. For searching a field which is of keyword type we have to search for it's exact term while for search a field of text type we can search  any one or more of the terms present in the actual text.

I've an index named sample_index which has two fields - description of type keyword and message of type text

**This is the mapping of the index named sample_index**
[image]

**Query**

```
POST sample_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

**This is the output of the above query:**
[image]

Here you can see that upon searching the word "keyword" which is present in description field (which is of keyword type), the results show up. But as per my understanding this is not possible right? because for keyword type , the whole text get's indexed as it is without getting split. How can this be possible or is something wrong with my understanding?

ES Version: 5.6.4

Comment: I could not reproduce, which version are you using ?

Comment: @Paulo version:  5.6.4

Comment: Ah! You should notify us of something like that .... current version is 8.2.2

Comment: @Paulo Sry, Will update it. I've included it in the tag though.

Comment: I update my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

In version `5.6` when using a [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

If no `default_field` is selected, it will turn to `_all` field.

The [_all field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/mapping-all-field.html) is a concatenation of all the fields in the document.

> The _all field is a special catch-all field which concatenates the values of all of the other fields into one big string, using space as a delimiter, which is then analyzed and indexed, but not stored. This means that it can be searched, but not retrieved.

This is why you have such a results

Comment: If they had only `keyword` types, it should have not returned any results. The result comes from a combination of `query_string` `default_field` and `text` type.

Answer (score 1):

Your `message` is actually of type `text`.
Additionally, you have a `field` of type `keyword` on `message`, but not relevant for your search query.

Because you're using `query_string`, which searches on all fields by default, your search query will match the "keyword" word in your `message` of type `text`. This is why you're able to search for the word "keyword", because `text` types get analyzed.

### From [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-query-ex-request) documentation

> default_field Defaults to the index.query.default_field index setting, which has a default value of *.

### [Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) documentation

> It is often useful to index the same field in different ways for different purposes. This is the purpose of multi-fields. For instance, a string field could be mapped as a text field for full-text search, and as a keyword field for sorting or aggregations:

Comment: I believe in the example ... the `description` does not have multifield. it is only a keyword

Comment: This is because query_string searches on all fields, by default. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Allan if this is the solution to your question, please accept the answer, thank you! :)

Comment: @Paulo's answer solved my doubts. Thanks for your answer too.